# How to lfs track in a bare repo?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I installed lfs on my bare repo, but now I can't track any files. When I run `git lfs track '*.png'` I get this error `This operation must be run in a work tree`. From what I understand this happens because this repo doesn't have a working directory. How am I supposed to choose which files should be tracked? Should I do it in the clone of this repo? This seems problematic as I will have to do it every time I clone it.

Comment: Consider cloning the bare repo elsewhere first.

Comment: I already did. I get this error when i try to push to the bare repo fom the cloned one.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Clone the repo (don't use `--bare` for the clone), and push to the bare repo when done. The bare repo doesn't need a work tree.

Comment: That's exactly what I do, and then I get this error.